# Exact sequence construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Given an $R$-module $M$ arbitrary, show it is always possible to construct an exact sequence of $R$-modules
$$0\longrightarrow K \longrightarrow  L \longrightarrow  M \longrightarrow 0,$$
with $L$ a free module.

I thought of considering $ K $ as being a free module and consider $ f: K \longrightarrow f (K) $, a homomorphism, which will be bijetor in the image, will soon take the basis of $ K $ in the base of $ f (K )$.

But I could not conclude anything with that.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971083/surjection-from-a-free-r-module-onto-an-r-module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always may write an $R$-module $M$ as a quotient of a free $R$-module $L$, for instance, if $S$ is any generating set for $M$,  the free $R$-module $L=R^{(S)}$, with basis $(e_s)_{s\in S}$, where  each $e_s$ is defined as 
$$e_s[i]=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }i=s,\\ 0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

The surjective homomorphism from $L$ to $M$ is defined as
\begin{align}
f:L&\longrightarrow M \\
\sum_{s\in S}\lambda_s e_s&\longmapsto \sum_{s\in S}\lambda_s\, s&&\text{(the sums are actually finite, by definition of $R^{(S)})$.}
\end{align}
If you denote $K$ the kernel of this linear map, you obtain the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow K\longrightarrow L\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow 0.$$
However, in general, $K$ (a.k.a. the module of linear relations between the generators in $S$) has no reason to be a `free` module.